# Reusing Spring MVC to build Application (Java)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am sure that i think reasonably but just to make sure...

**1.** If i start developing a web site (sheet based for calculations) in `Spring MVC`, i will be able to reuse the `Model` and `Controller` to create desktop application?

**2.** Also if i use `Spring MVC` because its `Java`, user doesn't need to have installed Java on his computer or device, because all the code is executing on `server-side`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The purpose of having a Model-View-Controller architecture is to be able to separate the model (how you represent the data) from the view (how you display it) and the controller (how you act on it). This means that a well-designed program can often use the same model for multiple interfaces, especially when the model is designed as its own library. That said, these days it's probably easier to maintain a single HTML UI and use a browser interface even if the program is locally installed.
2. Correct; the user of a Web application is interacting with it over HTTP, and the interface is in HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. The way that you run your application on your own server (with Spring MVC or anything else) doesn't matter to the client, which just needs a Web browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a Web-application now, but base it on AJAX, so that most of the work goes on between GUI-specific JavaScript in the browser and GUI-agnostic code on the server, then you'll probably be able to reuse much of the code on the server after you switch to a desktop app, which again depends on the same Web services (a Rich Client-style app).

If you plan to do a classical Web app which expects the server-side to render its HTML, and then later a standalone desktop app, then don't expect any reuse at the level of the Controller.

Answer (score 0):

1. You would be able to Reuse the `Model` but I do not think you can re-use the controller. In  my opinion controller uses `View` which can not be used in Desktop client.
2. If you are using Spring MVC and developing the web-application then user does not require to install Java.